# MySQL join two tables with multiple entry on same date on the second table

Tags: mysql

I have this 2 tables:

```
table1:
---------

UserID:     Date:       Day_status:
-----------------------------------
3004     2010-01-01     Normal
3004     2010-01-12     Normal
3004     2010-01-15     Ignore
3004     2010-01-18     Abnormal
4001     2010-01-09     Normal
4001     2010-01-11     Ignore
4001     2010-02-10     Normal
4001     2010-02-12     Abnormal
------------------------------------

table:2
-------
UserID:     Date:       Time          Height
--------------------------------------------
3004     2010-01-01     08:01:02       35
3004     2010-01-01     09:01:12       32
3004     2010-01-01     18:01:02       40

3004     2010-01-02     07:01:02       20
3004     2010-01-02     08:01:02       30
3004     2010-01-02     10:01:02       10

3004     2010-01-08     07:01:02       20
3004     2010-01-08     08:01:02       30
3004     2010-01-08     10:01:02       10

3004     2010-01-12     07:01:02       30
3004     2010-01-12     09:01:02       50
3004     2010-01-12     18:01:02       30

3004     2010-01-15     07:01:02       30
3004     2010-01-15     09:01:02       50
3004     2010-01-15     18:01:02       30

3004     2010-01-18     07:01:02       30
3004     2010-01-18     09:01:02       50
3004     2010-01-18     18:01:02       30

4001     2010-01-08     07:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-08     08:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-08     09:01:02       40
4001     2010-01-08     13:01:02       30

4001     2010-01-09     07:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-09     08:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-09     09:01:02       40

4001     2010-01-11     08:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-11     09:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-11     18:01:02       30

4001     2010-01-12     08:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-12     09:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-12     18:01:02       30

4001     2010-01-13     08:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-13     09:01:02       30
4001     2010-01-13     18:01:02       30

4001     2010-02-12     08:01:02       30
4001     2010-02-12     09:01:02       30
4001     2010-02-12     09:01:02       30
-----------------------------------------------
```

Please remember that, in table1: a user can have multiple 'Date's(users 3004 has multiple Date). And, in table2,

a user can have multiple 'Date' and each Date can have multiple 'Time'. In table2, user 3004 has 3 different 'Time's for the Date '2011-01-01' and so on.

I want to join these two tables so that,

1) all the data from table2 and only the Day_status data from table1 is included in the result.

2) if there is no 'Day_status' for the date of table2 in table1, the Day_status for that date in the result will be shown as 'Normal' (note: table 2 has more date entry than table1)

3) The entry with Day_status='Ignore' from table1 will not be in the final result

The output will be like this:

```
UserID:     Date:       Time          Height     Day_status_val
---------------------------------------------------------------
3004     2010-01-01     08:01:02       35        Normal
3004     2010-01-01     09:01:12       32        Normal
3004     2010-01-01     18:01:02       40        Normal

3004     2010-01-02     07:01:02       20        Normal
3004     2010-01-02     08:01:02       30        Normal
3004     2010-01-02     10:01:02       10        Normal

3004     2010-01-08     07:01:02       20        Normal
3004     2010-01-08     08:01:02       30        Normal
3004     2010-01-08     10:01:02       10        Normal

3004     2010-01-12     07:01:02       30        Normal
3004     2010-01-12     09:01:02       50        Normal
3004     2010-01-12     18:01:02       30        Normal

3004     2010-01-18     07:01:02       30        Abnormal
3004     2010-01-18     09:01:02       50        Abnormal
3004     2010-01-18     18:01:02       30        Abnormal

4001     2010-01-08     07:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-08     08:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-08     09:01:02       40        Normal
4001     2010-01-08     13:01:02       30        Normal 

4001     2010-01-09     07:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-09     08:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-09     09:01:02       40        Normal

4001     2010-01-12     08:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-12     09:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-12     18:01:02       30        Normal

4001     2010-01-13     08:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-13     09:01:02       30        Normal
4001     2010-01-13     18:01:02       30        Normal

4001     2010-02-12     08:01:02       30        Abnormal
4001     2010-02-12     09:01:02       30        Abnormal
4001     2010-02-12     09:01:02       30        Abnormal
-----------------------------------------------
```

I used the following query for getting my result:

```
SELECT table2.UserID, table2.Date, table2.Time, table2.Height,

CASE
   when table1.Day_status='Abnormal Day' then 'Abnormal Day'
   when table1.Day_status='Normal Day' then 'Normal Day'
   else 'Normal Day'
END as Day_status_val

FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1
ON table2.UserID = table1.UserID and table1.Day_status !='Ignore'
```

But, it gives faulty result. Can anyone please help me regarding this. Please look at the data in table1 and table2 and my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're nearly there. You need to add an extra ON clause to match the Date fields and you can use IFNULL to get the right Day_status.

```
SELECT t2.UserID,t2.Date,t2.Time,t2.Height,IFNULL(t1.Day_status,'Normal')
FROM table2 t2 
    LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON  t2.UserID = t1.UserID 
    AND t1.Day_status !='Ignore' 
    AND t2.`Date`=t1.`Date`
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks a lot for the help. I will try it out.